# How to update react HOC component with redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-functions

Below is the HOC and it is connected to redux store too. The WrappedComponent function is not fetching the redux state on change of storedata. What could be wrong here?

```
export function withCreateHOC<ChildProps>(
  ChildComponent: ComponentType,
  options: WithCreateButtonHOCOptions = {
    title: 'Create',
  },
) {
  function WrappedComponent(props: any) {
    const { createComponent, title } = options;
    const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);

    function onCreateClick() {
      setisOpen(!isOpen);
      Util.prevDefault(() => setisOpen(isOpen));
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent {...props} />
        <div>
          <Component.Button
            key={'add'}
            big={true}
            round={true}
            primary={true}
            onClick={Util.prevDefault(onCreateClick)}
            className={'float-right'}
            tooltip={title}
          >
            <Component.Icon material={'add'} />
          </Component.Button>
        </div>
        <OpenDrawerWithClose
          open={isOpen}
          title={title}
          setisOpen={setisOpen}
          createComponent={createComponent}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
    console.log('HOC mapStateToProps isOpen', state.isOpen);
    return {
      isOpen: state.isOpen,
    };
  }
  // Redux connected;
  return connect(mapStateToProps, {})(WrappedComponent);
}
```

Expecting **isOpen** to be used from *ReduxStore* and update the same with **WrappedComponent** here. By any chance this should be changed to class component?

**The above HOC is used as:**

```
export const Page = withCreateHOC(
  PageItems,
  {
    createComponent: <SomeOtherComponent />,
    title: 'Create',
  },
);
```

Comment: are the props of the WrappedComponent empty, or do you have issues binding the isOpen to the state of the WrappedComponent?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example in a sandbox

Comment: The question is, is `props.isOpen` in `WrappedComponent` really empty, or are you just missing the connection between the `isOpen` from useState and the props?

Comment: props.isOpen is empty in wrappedComponent. I am missing the link, can we update the state directly from the redux to wrappedcomponent or should there be isOpen prop to be sent?

Comment: wrappedComponent is maintained through state

Comment: please make a codesandbox

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa Feels like a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) problem, can't follow what your code does since you seem to have found an unusual solution to a problem you thought you had. Maybe you can try state setter with callback: `setisOpen(o=>!o); `

Comment: @HMR - I was using the same callback as you mentioned, but there is one more region from where i should call this state change which is independent. The implementation of the HOC feels wrong but designed by someone else

Comment: There are some wierd challenges here not sure how to explain or get this inside codebox. Forget codesandbox, i cannot get there, because this is Kubernetes Lens Electronjs project

Comment: You don't need to recreate ALL your project, just esolate the SPECIFIC minimal example, please read why and how: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You don’t want isOpen to be a local state in WrappedComponent.  The whole point of this HOC is to access isOpen from your redux store.  Note that nowhere in this code are you *changing* the value of your redux state.  You want to ditch the local state, access isOpen from redux through the props of WrappedComponent (added by connect), and dispatch an action to change isOpen in redux.  I can write up an answer later today if no one beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Overview

You don't want `isOpen` to be a local state in `WrappedComponent`. The whole point of this HOC is to access `isOpen` from your redux store. Note that nowhere in this code are you changing the value of your redux state. You want to ditch the local state, access `isOpen` from redux, and `dispatch` an action to change `isOpen` in redux.

Additionally we've got to replace some of those `any`s with actual types!

It seems a little suspect to me that you are passing a resolved JSX element rather than a callable component as `createComponent` (`<SomeOtherComponent />` vs `SomeOtherComponent`), but whether that is correct or a mistake depends on what's in your `OpenDrawerWithClose` component.  I'm going to assume it's correct as written here.

There's nothing technically wrong with using `connect`, but it feels kinda weird to use an HOC inside of an HOC so I am going to use the hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` instead.

#### Step By Step

We want to create a function that takes a component `ComponentType<ChildProps>` and some options `WithCreateButtonHOCOptions`.  You are providing a default value for `options.title` so we can make it optional.  Is `options.createComponent` optional or required?

```
interface WithCreateButtonHOCOptions {
    title: string;
    createComponent: React.ReactNode;
}
```

```
function withCreateHOC<ChildProps>(
  ChildComponent: ComponentType<ChildProps>,
  options: Partial<WithCreateButtonHOCOptions>
) {
```

We return a function that takes the same props, but without `isOpen` or `toggleOpen`, if those were properties of `ChildProps`.

```
return function (props: Omit<ChildProps, 'isOpen' | 'toggleOpen'>) {
```

We need to set defaults for the `options` in the destructuring step in order to set only one property.

```
const { createComponent, title = 'Create' } = options;
```

We access `isOpen` from the redux state.

```
const isOpen = useSelector((state: { isOpen: boolean }) => state.isOpen);
```

We create a callback that dispatches an action to redux -- you will need to handle this in your reducer.  I am dispatching a raw action object `{type: 'TOGGLE_OPEN'}`, but you could make an action creator function for this.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const toggleOpen = () => {
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_OPEN'});
}
```

We will pass these two values `isOpen` and `toggleOpen` as props to `ChildComponent` just in case it want to use them.  But more importantly, we can use them as click handlers on your button and drawer components.  (Note: it looks like drawer wants a prop `setIsOpen` that takes a `boolean`, so you may need to tweak this a bit.  If the drawer is only shown when `isOpen` is `true` then just toggling should be fine).

#### Code

```
function withCreateHOC<ChildProps>(
    ChildComponent: ComponentType<ChildProps>,
    options: Partial<WithCreateButtonHOCOptions>
) {
    return function (props: Omit<ChildProps, 'isOpen' | 'toggleOpen'>) {
        const { createComponent, title = 'Create' } = options;

        const isOpen = useSelector((state: { isOpen: boolean }) => state.isOpen);

        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const toggleOpen = () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_OPEN' });
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent
                    {...props as ChildProps}
                    toggleOpen={toggleOpen}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                />
                <div>
                    <Component.Button
                        key={'add'}
                        big={true}
                        round={true}
                        primary={true}
                        onClick={toggleOpen}
                        className={'float-right'}
                        tooltip={title}
                    >
                        <Component.Icon material={'add'} />
                    </Component.Button>
                </div>
                <OpenDrawerWithClose
                    open={isOpen}
                    title={title}
                    setisOpen={toggleOpen}
                    createComponent={createComponent}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This version is slightly better because it does not have the `as ChildProps` assertion.  I don't want to get too sidetracked into the "why" but basically we need to insist that if `ChildProps` takes an `isOpen` or `toggleOpen` prop, that those props must have the same types as the ones that we are providing.

```
interface AddedProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    toggleOpen: () => void;
}

function withCreateHOC<ChildProps>(
    ChildComponent: ComponentType<Omit<ChildProps, keyof AddedProps> & AddedProps>,
    options: Partial<WithCreateButtonHOCOptions>
) {
    return function (props: Omit<ChildProps, keyof AddedProps>) {
        const { createComponent, title = 'Create' } = options;

        const isOpen = useSelector((state: { isOpen: boolean }) => state.isOpen);

        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const toggleOpen = () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_OPEN' });
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent
                    {...props}
                    toggleOpen={toggleOpen}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                />
                <div>
                    <Component.Button
                        key={'add'}
                        big={true}
                        round={true}
                        primary={true}
                        onClick={toggleOpen}
                        className={'float-right'}
                        tooltip={title}
                    >
                        <Component.Icon material={'add'} />
                    </Component.Button>
                </div>
                <OpenDrawerWithClose
                    open={isOpen}
                    title={title}
                    setisOpen={toggleOpen}
                    createComponent={createComponent}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/qNB2pN)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, i have not tested so far. But i accept this for the attempt of clearing some major doubts. Only request is, can this be handled efficiently with Mobx?

Comment: I honestly have no idea because I do not use mobx.  I only use redux.